# Installing Windows After installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I had only Ubuntu installed in my system. I formatted the drive in which Ubuntu was installed and trying to install the windows 7 from past 4 days.

Initially Windows was showing an alert saying "Windows can't be installed in this disk. Select Disk has MBR style partition." For this I did following:

- Booted the system in Ubuntu(Try Ubuntu without installing).
- Ran `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`.
- selected `n`(for new partition)... in the end I selected `GUID` as `0700`(Microsoft Basic Data).

Then I tried booting system again in windows Then it says "windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk is of the gpt partition style."

I tried to do some other stuff too, I tried to select `ef00`(`EFI System` Didn't work), `0c01`(`Microsoft Reserverd` didn't work).

I tried few stuff in windows too, using `Diskpart`, according to net tutorials, I need to run `clean`(which will wipe all the data from other partitions too), but I don't want to format my drive.

Please help, let me know if you need anything else.

PS:  I have Followed -[this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from)- too, so please don't suggest this or mark it as duplicate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @TechLife I am not sure when did that happened but all of my partitions converted to primary partitions(added an Image), previously "Media, Setups and Docs" were extended partitions. I think we have to find some tool for Ubuntu, I don't have Windows Installed right now.

Comment: so you have the iso right? use this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu   or this is better    http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-iso-to-a-usb-device   put partition wizard iso on usb

Comment: @TechLife I have booted from USB. I am on Ubuntu Right now... not sure what to do here.

Comment: Windows only allows 4 primary partitions. Change it back to MBR, and use GPartEd (or alike) to convert the data partitions into logical partitions inside an extended partition.  Leave the area you want to install Windows to as "Unallocated", then try again.

Comment: @TechLife was doing some random experiments on GParted and lost all of my data. :'(

Comment: @BharatSoni you can recover your files after this too! but make a choice are you a fan of piracy? if yes OH yeah go here http://onhax.net/active-boot-disk-suite/ if not go and spend a bunch of bucks on here: http://www.lsoft.net/bootdisk.aspx

Comment: @TechLife not sure if it will work, I have formatted the disk twice, changed partition table.

Comment: what the ....? but unless you haven't written anything to it the data is there, no matter it has partition or not. Anyway in the future try not to install ubuntu first, The windows should be always installed first, in this case you can install any OS after windows, Thats why I love windows.

Comment: @TechLife Thanks a lot sir!! I will take care of what you said for future references. and agin, you are the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows 7 installation disk you can format the drive from the disk. Windows is very picky on how the drive its installing on needs to be formatted. If that doesn't work use a Windows xp installation disk just to format the drive.

Comment: I have a lot of data in my HDD, wiping all data is not an option :)

Comment: @Bharat I'm sorry unless you do virtual box or wipe it won't work. Windows get jealous when installing and wants all the space. p.s. I'm hardly a genius

Answer (score 0):

I done this exact thing before: (But this erases all your data)

Delete All Partitions, except one which is you can't erase, and make a new one. Set it as the default, and install windows on the old one.

Comment: OP states data on partitions so wipe not an option

Comment: Make a new one. Set it as default, then prompt to delete the main one. It will say that all data will be gone. Say yes. Then install OS on new one, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

(MBR) can have four primary partitions.  One of them can be an extended partition, which can contain any number of logical partitions.

GPT partition scheme which cannot hold the boot volume for a Windows 7 machine

Edit: Also you can try this [GPT to MBR](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26203-convert-gpt-disk-mbr-disk.html)

You need to use windows live .iso or you can use cmd when you use repair system from cd/pendrive.

Comment: 4 four primary partitions is a limitation of disk format (MBR), not actually of Windows.